# Is there a way to shorten these PictureBox Subs?

Tags: vb.net

I have 9 PictureBoxes on my form. Every single PictureBox got its own DoubleClick event handler. I haven't yet found a way to combine these 9 subs into one; especially because the bitmap list (List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)) must have a different number of `.count`.
If you click on a PictureBox, only code for *this* should be executed.

```
   Private Sub PictureBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 0 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(0)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(0)
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 1 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(1)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(1)
            PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox3_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 2 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(2)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(2)
            PictureBox3.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 3 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(3)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(3)
            PictureBox4.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox5_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 4 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(4)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(4)
            PictureBox5.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox6_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox6.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 5 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(5)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(5)
            PictureBox6.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox7_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox7.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 6 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(6)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(6)
            PictureBox7.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox8_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox8.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 7 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(7)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(7)
            PictureBox8.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox9_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox9.DoubleClick
        
        If BitmapList IsNot Nothing AndAlso BitmapList.Count > 8 Then
            BitmapList.RemoveAt(8)
            Path_List.RemoveAt(8)
            PictureBox9.Image = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting the `Tag` property of each `PictureBox` to the corresponding number in the designer, i.e. `PictureBox1.Tag` to 0, etc. You can then combine all those event handlers into one:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBoxes_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox2.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox3.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox4.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox5.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox6.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox7.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox8.DoubleClick,
                                                                               PictureBox9.DoubleClick
    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim n = CInt(pb.Tag)

    If BitmapList?.Count > n Then
        BitmapList.RemoveAt(n)
        Path_List.RemoveAt(n)
        pb.Image.Dispose()
        pb.Image = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I added a line to dispose the `Image` you're removing. Don't do that if you're still using the `Image` object elsewhere but definitely do it if you're not still using it.

Note that I also threw a null propagation operator in there, negating the need for a separate null check.

Comment: Many Thanks! That works fine for me. Topic done. PS: I am aware of the need to ```.Dispose()``` an image object; it is written elsewhere, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Don't even need to set the tag; you can get the number by `int.Parse(DirectCast(sender, Control).Name.Replace("PictureBox",""))-1` (or name PictureBox0..9 and forget the -1). Why not just store the bitmap and path in the Tag though, ditch the bitmaplist and the pathlist

Comment: @CaiusJard, that's true but I personally find parsing the control name to be a bit hacky and something that should be a last resort. If the names were changed to something more descriptive that did not include a number then this code would still work. As for the other stuff, that's a question for the OP and beyond the scope of this answer to the question as it was asked. If you were going to go that way though, I might be inclined to define a custom control with dedicated properties rather than overusing the `Tag`.